# Unavailable time of an Entry if we use Table.putItem to Update an Entry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, high-availability

Here I want to use DynamoDB SDK Table.putItem to update an entry. But I want that to be available even by the time it got updated. 
My question is there any known down time where the entry is not available to read when the entry got replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of consistency models available in DynamoDB. Eventually Consistent Reads is the default consistency which gives the latest copy within a second.

I think you are looking for **Strongly Consistent Reads**. However, in my experience, I don't think DynamoDB provides 100% guarantee that it will always return the latest value especially when you are reading the same item just after updating the item in the database.

> Eventually Consistent Reads (Default) – the eventual consistency
>   option maximizes your read throughput. However, an eventually
>   consistent read might not reflect the results of a recently completed
>   write. Consistency across all copies of data is usually reached within
>   a second. Repeating a read after a short time should return the
>   updated data.
>
> Strongly Consistent Reads — in addition to eventual consistency,
>   Amazon DynamoDB also gives you the flexibility and control to request
>   a strongly consistent read if your application, or an element of your
>   application, requires it. A strongly consistent read returns a result
>   that reflects all writes that received a successful response prior to
>   the read.